# Get second occurrence from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string str="Customer was charged £10,000 and £11,000 for the same service in June and July respectively".
```

I want to fetch the second amount from the string.

I am using below expression but it is only giving the first value that is £10,000.

```
string m = Regex.Match(str, @"\£[^ ]+").Value.ToString();
```

Please let me know how can i skip the first one and pick directly the second value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Matches()` to get all possible results and `Skip(1)` to skip the first

```
string str = "Customer was charged £10,000 and £11,000 for the same service in June and July respectively";
string m = Regex.Matches(str, @"\£[^ ]+").Cast<Match>().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()?.Value?.ToString();
```